# Images are different sizes coming from a database

Tags: php

Storing images in a database and outputting them to my website, however, they are coming out different sizes.

Tried to alter my CSS but not sure what I should be tagging to alter

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category LIKE '%$search%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div id = 'img_div'>";
    echo "<img src ='img/".$row['image']."'>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['description']."</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['category']."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same ID for every image. Give them a class, and then set the height and width for the class.

```
?>
<style type="text/css">
.img_div > img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category LIKE '%$search%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='img_div'>";
    echo "<img src='img/".$row['image']."'>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['description']."</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['category']."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```